# How to separate disk partition after complete installation?

Tags: 13.04, hard-drive, partitioning

I have following setup.i want a new separate 200gb partition. i'll try fdisk /dev/sda to command new partition via but i can't exactly.i need help

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x000216a9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968587263   484292608   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968589310   976771071     4090881    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       968589312   976771071     4090880   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: please upload the gparted screenshot in `imgur.com` and post the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `move/resize/delete` a partition in Ubuntu through **gparted**.Run the below commands in terminal to install `gparted`.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
sudo gparted
```

**Please note that,by this method you can `resize/delete` a partition through gparted only if it was unmounted.**

To `resize/delete` a mounted partition then you can use [**gparted-live-disk**](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php).

Comment: Thanks...but i would like COMMAND mode

Comment: does it works for you.

Comment: i'm not try i except cmd mode

Comment: not work could not unmount /dev/sda1 because mount point is root  '\'

Comment: you cannot unmount a root partition.try gparted live disk to make partitions on root.

Comment: Gparted live disk ..???

Comment: see my answer,and click on the gparted-live-disk link,download the .iso file,through unetbootin software make the .iso bootable through usb.

Comment: Except Command mode,i don't like this way

Answer (score 0):

To change partitions they must not be mounted. I don't know whether fdisk will still work after unmounting /dev/sda1X, so I recommend the following solution:

**Create a backup of your important data before doing this. Partitioning may harm existing partitions.**

1. Boot your Live Ubuntu (the one on your installation media)
2. Open GParted (if not working: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> -> `sudo gparted`)
3. Change size of /dev/sdb1 (Actual device name may differ, just search the correct one)
4. Create new partition
5. Commit changes (may take a while)
6. reboot

Comment: I except COMMAND mode to change